# How to share both NSAttritutedString and localfile(NSURL) using UIActivityItemProvider for UIActivityTypeMail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am written this code in `MyActivityItemProvider`,
`[sharedObject objectForKey:@"Mail"]` is `NSArray` containing `NSAttributedString` and `NSURL` for local file in mobile Storage,
I am unable to share both,
Please help any one

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{

    if([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail])

    {

       if ([sharedObject objectForKey:@"Mail"])

       {   
            return [sharedObject objectForKey:@"Mail"][0];
       }

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You should be able to use the `NSTextAttachment` class to directly insert the file(s) you want to send into your `NSAttributedString`.</s>

## Edit

*It looks like NSTextAttachments are ignored here.*

While `UIActivityItemProvider` appears only able to represent a single sharable item (no returned arrays allowed), you can have multiple `UIActivityItemProvider`s.

When you initialize your `UIActivityViewController`, simply pass it 2 different items. Here is an example where I've used a property on a single `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass to determine if it should return the body or an attachment.

```
MyItemSource *itemSourceBody = [[MyItemSource alloc] init];
itemSourceBody.returnAttachment = NO;
MyItemSource *itemSourceAttachment = [[MyItemSource alloc] init];
itemSourceBody.returnAttachment = YES;

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[itemSourceBody, itemSourceAttachment] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When `returnAttachment` is false, it returns the email body, when true it returns a URL to a locally stored PDF.

**This is just an example, and not well architected.**

Additionally, if you don't need a lot of customization, you could just initialize `UIActivityViewController` directly with your `NSAttributedString` and `NSURL` without the `UIActivityItemProvider` middleman.

Comment: This is not work with pdf file, Any other solution for pdf file.

Comment: Please let me know if this new solution works for you.

Comment: @SamFalconer Is there any way to send multiple file URLs from a single UIActivityItemProvider class? If I use NSDictionary to pass multiple items, it works, but shows each item twice in the target app. Any idea, how to do it? (Sending array of urls does not work.!)